# Как перенести пользователя в корзину с несколькими товарами?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Подготавливаю шаблон письма и нужно, чтобы по клику по кнопке клиент переходил в корзину с заранее выбранными мной товарами.
Заранее товары добавить в корзину не могу — ссылка не персональная на корзину, а общая (у клиента откроется просто пустая корзина). Если добавить ссылку с кнопки «Купить», которая стоит рядом с товаром, то он добавится у клиента и будет в корзине. Но нужно добавлять несколько разных товаров.
Поэтому прошу у вас помощи — как сделать так, чтобы по клику добавлялись 4 товара сразу (может как-то открывать 4 ссылки с кнопок «Купить») или давать ссылку на корзину с заполненными товарами (может её как-то можно всё таки вытащить)?

Comment: он товар выбирает в своём личном кабинете? или ты за него выбираешь? и куда записи складируются в sql

Comment: Личный кабинет отсутствует. Я должен за него положить товары в корзину. Я не понял вопроса о sql. Записи о товаре хранится в таблице products

Comment: таблица в my sql создана?

Comment: Да, таблица создана там.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю сделать так:

1. Создать дополнительную сущность "акция/спецпредложение/промо" (далее "акция"). Хранить её в отдельной таблице (id, название акции, уникальный хэш, "список товаров акции"). "список товаров акции" - это или таблица связей "Товары акции" (многие-ко-многим) или просто поле в таблице акций (json-массив / сериализованный массив / строка с id товаров через запятую). Пример хэша: "05dbba941443332475b8e3f572f5d148".
2. К ссылке в письме добавлять хэш, например, GET-параметром (https://your.site/cart/?promo=05dbba941443332475b8e3f572f5d148).
3. При переходе на страницу корзины, перед формированием страницы корзины, в PHP проверять наличие GET-параметра и запускать функцию добавления в корзину товаров "список товаров акции".